# SELECT COUNT() INSIDE A SELECT MAX() SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count, max

I've got this table called `player_mast` in a db (data are just an example), and I want to find the club which supplied the most number of players to the 2016 EURO cup.

| player_id | country_id | jersey_no | player_name | posi_to_play | dt_of_bir | age | playing_club |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1231 | 1231 | 10 | Hazard | striker | 2/3/1991 | 33 | Chelsea |

Why this query doesn't work? It seems right to me:

```
SELECT playing_club, MAX(NumberOfPlayerForTeam)
FROM (
  SELECT playing_club, COUNT(player_id) AS NumberOfPlayerForTeam
  FROM player_mast
  GROUP BY(playing_club))
GROUP BY(playing_club);
```

Comment: What *specifically* happens with the query? Wrong answer? Error message? If the latter, *what* message was shown?

Comment: Either go with window functions. in MySQL version 8. Or do ORDER BY, LIMIT.

Comment: Nothing in your query has "2016" or "2016 World Cup".  So, I don't think the data supports your query.

Comment: It's an exercise, it's the db of euro 2016, every table data refers in an implicit way to EURO 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT playing_club, NumberOfPlayerForTeam<br>
FROM (<br>
  SELECT playing_club, COUNT(player_id) AS NumberOfPlayerForTeam<br>
  FROM player_mast<br>
  GROUP BY(playing_club))<br>
ORDER BY NumberOfPlayerForTeam DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: The outer select is IMHO not needed. You should be able to apply ORDER BY and LIMIT just after the GROUP BY.

Comment: yes, that is also one of solution. But I just want minimal change in user's own query. If required user can change this according to his own choice.

Comment: Yeah but if there is more than 1 team that provide the max number of players and I don't know this number of teams the "DESC LIMIT 1" won't produce a 100% true result or am I wrong? Especially in a Database that change often its Data this would be a problem.

Comment: ok..if that is the case then there will be different query. Can you share sample data script with create table script. Also, share the version of mysql you are using.

Comment: Yeah but it's an exercise in a sql editor on the browser: https://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/soccer-database-exercise/sql-subqueries-exercise-soccer-database-13.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want the playing clubs that have the most rows in your table, you can use `rank()`:

```
SELECT pm.*
FROM (SELECT playing_club, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfPlayerForTeam,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM player_mast
      GROUP BY playing_club
     ) pm
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Note:

- `COUNT(<column name>)` counts the number of non-`NULL` values in the column.  There is no need to do this additional check; `COUNT(*)` does what you want.
- Parentheses are not needed around the `GROUP BY` keys.